# Bind Click Event in WebView Android React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to bind click event inside webview 
Below is my code but its not working.

```
_renderContent() {
var s = '';
if(this.state.contents.length > 0) {
    this.state.contents.map(( guid, i) => {
     s += '<div style="font-size:48;padding-left:10px;"><button onClick =   alert("hi");>try<button></div>';
   });

  return (
     <WebView 
         source={ { html: s} }
         scalesPageToFit={true}
         startInLoadingState={false}
     /> 
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you close your button tag properly and maybe wrap your `alert('hi')` in quotes?

```
<div style="font-size:48;padding-left:10px;"><button onClick="alert('hi')";>try</button></div>
```

Comment: I have tried it didn't worked. It is working fine in iOs but not in android.

Comment: Oh good that it works in iOS. Then I'd just play with it until you figure out how to get it working in Android. What if you did this `javascript:alert('hi')`?

Comment: I have an Android. When use the same code in a jsfiddle, it works fine on my Android. So I think the code is good, but maybe it has something to do with your android setup, like maybe it doesn't work in genymotion or something. https://jsfiddle.net/zq1Lbf41/

Comment: I am using Android Studio Emulator and that code didnot work - http://screencast.com/t/6VqnHX2d

Comment: Send to be a problem with the emulator then. Not the code.